# Obtener el nombre de la fila y columna de una celda de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Necesito devolver el nombre de la fila y columna de una celda en la que estoy en un dataframe.

Por ejemplo, estando en `df.iloc[2,5] = 'XYZ'` necesito que me devuelva que está ubicado en fila `A` y columna `Fc`.

He intentado con el siguiente código pero me genera error

```
C = df.column(iloc[2,5]) # Deberia devolver Fc

F = df.index(iloc[2,5])  # Deberia devolver A
```

Gracias ¡¡

[image]

Comment: A ver, si ya sabes que lo que buscas está en la fila 2 y la columna 5, los nombres los obtendrías con `df.index[2]`  y `df.columns[5]`, respectivamente.

Comment: Ups... me estaba volviendo loco con esto y era muy facil. Gracias abulafia ¡¡¡